# Why does a T-SQL block give an error even if it shouldn't even be executed?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I was writing a (seemingly) straight-forward SQL snippet that drops a column after it makes sure the column exists.
The problem: if the column does NOT exist, the code *inside* the IF clause complains that it can't find the column! Well, *doh*, that's why it's inside the IF clause!
So my question is, why does a piece of code that shouldn't be executed give errors?

Here's the snippet:

```
IF exists (select * from syscolumns
    WHERE id=object_id('Table_MD') and name='timeout')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_MD]
        DROP COLUMN timeout
END
GO
```

...and here's the error:

`Error executing SQL script [...]. Invalid column name 'timeout'`

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
IF exists (select * from syscolumns
    WHERE id=object_id('Table_MD') and name='timeout')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
    SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_MD] DROP COLUMN timeout'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
GO
```

Reason:
When Sql server compiles the code, they check it for used objects ( if they exists ). This check procedure ignores any "IF", "WHILE", etc... constructs and simply check all used objects in code.

Comment: Correct.  You will also get this error if there are temporary tables lying around that the sproc uses.

Comment: To clarify, if a temporary table exists then the columns will be checked when you compile the sproc.  Where the sproc actually creates the table (for example with a select into) you may need to drop the table before recompiling the sproc.

Answer (score 0):

It may never be executed, but it's parsed for validity by Sql Server. The only way to "get around" this is to construct a block of dynamic sql and then selectively execute it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work:

Inside the IF clause, I changed the `ALTER ... DROP ...` command with `exec ('ALTER ... DROP ...')`

It seems the SQL server does a validity check on the code when parsing it, and sees that a non-existing column gets referenced somewhere (even if that piece of code will never be executed).
Using the `exec(ute)` command wraps the problematic code in a string, the parser doesn't complain, and the code only gets executed when necessary.
Here's the modified snippet:

```
IF exists (select * from syscolumns
    WHERE id=object_id('Table_MD') and name='timeout')
BEGIN
    exec ('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_MD] DROP COLUMN timeout')
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is a similar issue in Oracle, and a similar workaround using the "execute immediate" clause.