# Generate static SQL scripts for SQL objects instead of dynamic SQL when object existence check is turned ON

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I have kept "Check for object existence" option turned ON in my SQL Server Mgmt Studio, because I need SQL Server to automatically include "IF EXISTS" statements before dropping and recreating the objects.

Now, whenever I right-click and try to generate "Create and Drop scripts" for any objects, it puts the whole CREATE statement as a dynamic SQL which I think is a pure mess and more prone to errors.

Is there any option to make SSMS generating static SQL scripts when the object existence check is turned on?

I am using SSMS 2012.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on SO asking why SQL Server "ignores" `IF`s when doing `if not exists/create` blocks. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120966/15498), and all have the same explanation - SQL Server will throw an error when *compiling* the `CREATE` since the object already exists. So the alternative, no dynamic SQL, is to have scripts that generate errors. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has both `Drop If Exists` and `CREATE OR ALTER` but that doesn't help you as you are on 2012. the issue here is that `CREATE` has to be the only item in the batch for lots of object types so this is the only way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is the correct / best approach...

The problem is, that there is no `DROP_AND_CREATE` statement in T-SQL. Many people use something like

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME='SomeFunction')
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunction;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunction...
```

But this is problematic, if there are dependencies like a `CONSTRAINT` or a `GRANT` or other...

It is easier to use a check like above and decide if you create the `CREATE` statement or if you change the first word to `ALTER` dynamically. You cannot place both statements in some kind of conditional workflow, as it has to be *the first in batch*.

> ... pure mess and more prone to errors

Especially with a generated statement I would not expect errors... You are right, that this isn't pretty, but many code generators do not produce *pretty code*. That doesn't really matter...